# Converting $ax^3 + bx^2 +cx + d$ to $a(x-j)^3 +k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics, completing-the-square

We're all familiar with the vertex form of a quadratic function,$$a(x-p)^2 +q$$ where $(-p,q)$ represent the coordinates of the maximum or minimum point of the parabola. This is achieved by performing completing the square on the standard form of the quadratic function $ax^2+bx+c$.

My question is: can the same be done for cubic functions? Playing around with graphs have shown me that $$a(x-j)^3 +k$$ graphs a cubic function whose inflection point is $(-j,k)$. However, I have not been able to find a method of converting a standard cubic function $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ to its 'vertex form' as stated above that is applicable generally to all cubic functions.

I have tried geometrically 'completing the cube' with a friend and found a way (?) to convert standard cubic expressions to their vertex form, but this method was only applicable to cubics without a linear term. I'm looking for a general method that works for *all* cubics, I really appreciate the help!

**Edit**:
Okay, so I received a lot of feedback which explained why $a(x-j)^3 +k$ would not work for all cubic equations because it only has one real root, and got pointers in the direction of depressed cubic equations. My question is: is there a general way to show the position of the inflection point using the depressed cubic?

Comment: Usually one cannot: this is only possible if $3ac=b^2$.

Comment: Take a look at this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/4h2c1q/is_there_a_complete_the_cube_process_for_the_cubic/). In particular, by making the substitution $x = u+v$, you can reduce the cubic into the form $x^3-px=q$. The resulting cubic equation is called a 'depressed cubic'.

Comment: If $a\ne 0$ and $F(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d $, suppose $F(x)= a(x-j)^3+k$ for all $x$ then $F(x)=0$ would be easy to solve $F(x)=0$. Too easy.....  Substituting $x=t-b/3a$  into $a^{-1}F(x)=0$ gives a "depressed cubic" equation of the type  $t^3+pt+q=0 .$ See   
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Derivation_of_the_roots

Comment: If substitution $x\to A+\frac{1}{y}$ is acceptable, then for $y$ "complete cubic" is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that in general. Suppose that your cubic had $3$ real roots (example: $x^3-x$). Then you can't do that because $(x-j)^3+k$ has only one real root. So, they cannot be the same cubic.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression has only one real root but a cubic equation can have at most 3 real roots. To generalise the point of inflection you can use calculus. $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ Differentiate it twice and equate it to zero .

You'll get $3ax=-b$

Now you can get co-ordinate of $x=\frac{-b}{3a}$ calculate x and put back that in the cubic equation to get y coordinate

Answer (score 0):

Shifting $x$ by a carefully chosen constant can only delete one term in general, which we usually choose to be the $x^2$ one to obtain a *depressed* cubic, which if monic after division by $a$ is usually denoted $y^3+py+q,\,y:=x+\frac{b}{3a}$, Therefore, the solution isn't as simple as taking a cube root, However, [you can solve it](https://brilliant.org/wiki/cardano-method/).