# Can any cubic polynomial be transformed into canonical form?

Tags: cubics

Can any cubic polynomial be transformed from $Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$ to $a(b(x-h))^3 + k$?

For example, how could $x^3+\frac{3x^2}{2}+\frac{x}{2}$ be transformed?

Comment: As the question stands now, it seems to be asking whether you can transform a cubic into a quadratic, then there is a stray $n$ which looks out of place. Are those typos?

Comment: For the quadratic, that was a typo. For the stray n, I can’t see it…

Comment: The $\,n\,$ was in your [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4484464/1) but someone edited and fixed it since. The canonical form of a cubic is not a cube power. Instead, you can reduce it to a depressed cubic, see for example [Finding a substitution that eliminates the squared term from a cubic equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2424827/finding-a-substitution-that-eliminates-the-squared-term-from-a-cubic-equation).

Comment: Related $\;-\;$ [Converting $ax^3 + bx^2 +cx + d$ to $a(x-j)^3 +k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3401061/converting-ax3-bx2-cx-d-to-ax-j3-k).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking whether a cubic polynomial $ A x^3 + B x^2 + C x + D $ can be put in the form $ A (x - k)^3 + h $, then the answer is no.  While in the quadratic case it is always possible to convert $A x^2 + B x + C $ into the form $A (x - k)^2 + h $

However, it is possible to eliminate the $x^2$ term, by writing

$ A x^3 + B x^2 + C x + D = A (x - k)^3 + C_1 (x - k) + h$

Comparing the forms on the left and the right, we get

$ B = A (-3 k) $

$ C = A (9 k^2) + C_1 $

$ D = h - A k^3 - C_1 k $

From the first, one can find $k$, then from the second equation, one finds $C_1$, and finally from the third equation, one finds $h$.

Comment: Please respect [the guidelines for enforcing quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Thank you.

Comment: @Hosam Hajeer  note that you had a small mistake in the equation of C. Fixed it